# get time and date in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

i am using

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

but its always returning date and time form my PC.

Ex..  today is - 15/07/2015

and i changed my PC date to 17/09/2016

so php Date also returning same date...(17/09/2016)

is there any why to get real time and date?

what i have tried
1. simple date function
2. set timezone 
3. i have searched on google but no luck yet...

Comment: Since you probably have xampp or wampp something like this installed on your computer, your computer is the server, so: computer time = server time

Comment: Are you running of a server or your PC, What time zone is your PC set? PHP Doesn't have a Antenna To a satellite Or a GPS System

Comment: You'd think that something as important as time would be standardized on computers.  And you'd be right, it's just that there are many standards.  A further description of what your environment is would possibly be helpful. What operating system are you running?  PHP is cross-platform and you could be running in Linux, Windows or Mac OS environments, each of which may handle time and localization settings differently.  What version of PHP are you running?  This may also be a factor for someone who can actually answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always return your PC date as it well should.
Date & time functions use the server's date and time. So if you're running a local server (WAMP, XAMP or whatever) your PC will be the server and therefore it's time will be used.
Setting the timezone should change the time accordingly though.

Comment: so when i upload my script on main server so date will tack form my server date not form visitors pc?

Comment: @Rajeevvishva Yes. At least if you're doing `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` it will.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Nairobi');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

but as @Rizier123 said that if you are using XAMPP or WAMP or any other local server it will show the system time only. I would like to suggest you that put your code to an online server or use some [online php compiler](http://phpfiddle.org/), then it will surely gonna give you the expected output.